# Background image with repeat resize

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using a photo as a background and repeat it,but when I resize the window the img doesn't resize and the pattern change.

How can I fix this?

I am using Bootstrap.

```
body {
background-image: url("img/pattern.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x-y}
```

Comment: There is a background-size property in CSS. However it works by either containing or covering etc. the container the image sits within. I don't think you can do what you want with a repeating image using this property.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 2 ways , you can use which ever works

```
background-size: contain

background-size: cover
```

But using repeat , I am not sure how far you will be able to get the expected outcome

Comment: @jaafarkhansa.. why dont u use different images for different screen resolution and write media queries to call the corresponding image ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
background-size: contain
```